# Prove $\sum_{x=1}^{X} \sum_{y=1}^Y {Y \choose y} \times (x-1)^{Y-y} = X^Y$

Tags: summation

I accidentally find this property,  $\sum_{x=1}^{X} \sum_{y=1}^Y {Y \choose y} \times (x-1)^{Y-y} = X^Y$, when doing a brain-teaser. I only tried up to y=3, but it seems to be true for all X and Y. Can anyone give an induction prove? (or any direct prove is also appreciated)

Edit: It is ${Y \choose y}$ sorry!

Comment: Compute the inner sum (using the binomial formula) and see some telescoping.

Comment: I dislike the use of X and Y as the upper limits.

Comment: @martycohen Could you suggest a better symbol to use?

Comment: $m$ and $n$ would be my choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the binomial theorem

$$(a + b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} a^{n-k} b^k$$

In our case, we have:

$$(x-1 + 1)^Y = \sum_{y=0}^{Y} {Y \choose y}  (x-1)^{Y-y}\cdot 1^y$$
$$x^Y = (x-1)^Y+\sum_{y=1}^{Y} {Y \choose y}  (x-1)^{Y-y}$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{x=1}^{X} \sum_{y=1}^Y {Y \choose y} \times (x-1)^{Y-y}=\sum_{x=1}^{X}[x^Y- (x-1)^Y]= X^Y$$